# Amazon Web Services & Android Security Concern

Tags: android, security, amazon-web-services

I have recently started learning about amazon web services & trying to built a game application on top of it's solutions, there were couple of things bothered me while developing,

Is is possible to retrieve temporary credentials received by STS to use them manually? If yes, can we use them manually with other SDK?

Since it's possible to connect to dynamodb with those credentials it's sure that user can access or update his own data, but how secure is it? What if someone decompiles android app and change the code where I am updating user score to manual number, recompile and try to run it [I have never done it myself but read / heard that we can decompile and compile and rerun android app]

Is it possible that another app tampers my app on rooted phone and change data to dynamodb manually? Just like score boosters out there? Or AWS maintains the security for it?

Thanks everyone for reading, please help me out with these queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking AWS Mobile Hub https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub. Mobile Hub helps mobile developers get on board with AWS, configuring features, and creating a sample app that uses those features which you can then use as a building block for your real app.

To specifically answer your questions. For mobile developers, AWS Cognito https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito is the best way to vend credentials (Mobile Hub will help you set this up). It is possible for others to decompile your app and send bad data, but with Cognito and strong Identity and Access Manage policies https://aws.amazon.com/iam/ can limit the blast radius of a malicious user. Additionally you can use Lambda functions https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/ and API Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/ to set up your own anti-cheating system if you don't want to maintain your own server.

I know that's a lot. For getting started I would first checkout Mobile Hub and then the Android or iOS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/  or  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/

Hope this helps